# I'm looking to add membership to my site, any plugins that would be compatible

Tags: membership

To put it simply, I'm looking for users to be able to subscribe for 'X' amount a year. 
This would allow them to edit their own space on my site.

Once they subscribe, I'd like the plug-in to create a page for the user, allowing them to edit their page, and the posts on their page only.

If it helps I'm looking to create two membership levels at the moment:

**Subscriber**
Free

- Rate articles on the site
- Receive custom emails based on interests
- Follow other users and their activity
- Create a public profile, with limited information.

**User**
Paid

- Everything from Subscriber plus:
- As soon as they register they have the option to add information to one page, and one page only, with many post titles defined by me, where they can add in their information, for example: About Your Work, Bio.. Etc..
- Upload 5 pictures to become a gallery on their page.
- Add tags to their page, to put them into genres to allow for easy searching

In the future I'm looking to add another membership level where they would be reviewing other members, being able to leave comments on their work and gain reputation as they do.

Everything has to fit into my theme, I'll be doing all of the php,html,javascript and css work. What plugins would best suit this application?

I cannot seem to find any plug-ins that do just this, all of the ones I've found allow access to restricted content.. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at S2 Member http://www.s2member.com/

> The s2Member® Framework is an extremely versatile & powerful (free) membership management plugin for WordPress®. The s2Member® Framework plugin integrates seamlessly with PayPal® Standard Buttons (very easy), and fully supports recurring billing, with the ability to track affiliate commissions on a recurring basis (through your choice of many affiliate platforms). s2Member® supports custom Pages for registration; including Custom Registration/Profile Fields, account access, and a whole lot more! See expanding features below.

Answer (score 0):

The WPMUdev have developed a great and suitable plugin for your situation which have a really cool documentation. Its name is Membership plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/membership/
Docs:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/#usage